# React Native App crashes due to UnsatisfiedLinkError on alpha version

Tags: android, react-native, release

My react native app seems to be fine on emulator as well on device if i install over android studio or `react-native run-android`.
I tried both debug as well release variation.

The signed APK of the alpha release crashes as soon as Ibisen the App after downloading the version from google play console. Is there any special flags i need to consider?

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName (SoLoader.java:703)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName (SoLoader.java:564)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary (SoLoader.java:500)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary (SoLoader.java:455)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.staticInit (ReactBridge.java:18)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap.<clinit> (NativeMap.java:19)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSCJavaScriptExecutorFactory.create (JSCJavaScriptExecutorFactory.java:21)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run (ReactInstanceManager.java:917)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

unzip -l app.aab | grep lib lists me the following

```
    1607  02-03-2019 20:40   base/res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ressources_libra1.png
    87552  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/armeabi-v7a/libfb.so
   112136  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/armeabi-v7a/libfolly_json.so
    79448  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/armeabi-v7a/libglog.so
    17920  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/armeabi-v7a/libglog_init.so
   718696  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so
   922976  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/armeabi-v7a/libicu_common.so
   255952  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/armeabi-v7a/libimagepipeline.so
  1910900  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so
     9676  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/armeabi-v7a/libprivatedata.so
   329236  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/armeabi-v7a/libreactnativejni.so
   144920  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/armeabi-v7a/libyoga.so
   140800  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/x86/libfb.so
   198112  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/x86/libfolly_json.so
    99824  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/x86/libglog.so
    30176  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/x86/libglog_init.so
  1070960  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/x86/libgnustl_shared.so
  1307892  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/x86/libicu_common.so
   473052  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/x86/libimagepipeline.so
  4614240  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/x86/libjsc.so
     5472  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/x86/libprivatedata.so
   755216  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/x86/libreactnativejni.so
   247256  02-03-2019 20:40   base/lib/x86/libyoga.so
```

and have already the following in my gradle file

```
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

This only happens when I create a signed bundle. If i create an APK and install to device, it's still fine.